# How to only keep one row of data and delete others in a three-month window?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with attributes `date, name, sex, id, status`
date is in format datetime.

I want to group by `name, sex, id` and only keep one data in a **three-month** window and drop other rows.

For example

```
2017-12-01, A, MALE, 123
2017-10-01, A, MALE, 123
2017-09-01, A, MALE, 123
2016-08-02, A, MALE, 123
2017-09-01, B, MALE, 123
2016-08-02, B, MALE, 123
```

I only want to keep any row in a three-month window after group by those three attributes

```
2017-09-01, A, MALE, 123 (any first three rows work)
2016-08-02, A, MALE, 123
2017-09-01, B, MALE, 123
2016-08-02, B, MALE, 123
```

How could I do that in SQL, is it possible?

Comment: You can use date diff function in your query https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Comment: 'Any'? :-( Decide which one you want to keep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```
select name,sex,id
from table
group by name,sex,id
having datediff(mm,date,getdate())<3
```

and if you want to delete you should change to datediff>3

Comment: I love how there is an heart at the end <3 - Good answer, my prefered way to do it

Comment: @Hello_my_dog_can_code This answer uses a GROUP BY clause but no aggregating functions. By no stretch of the imagination can this be considered 'good'

Comment: well, of course you could replace the group by with a simple where clause

Comment: Why you use getdate() here? Little confused by it

Comment: Assuming that you should compare the date from your table with the current date

Comment: @Strawberry It's only a draft idea. You would put count(1) or anything you want, it depends...

Comment: @sorineatza But I want to only keep one data in the rows that are grouped together if they are different by less than 3 months, not the current date. Why I need the current date?

Comment: @Chen What do you mean "different by less than 3 months"? Different between the dates from records? Or how?

Comment: @sorineatza Different between the dates from records that are in the same group

Answer (score 0):

This solution would be ok:

```
select min(date) over (partition by name,sex,id) as dmin,
max(date) over (partition by name,sex,id) as dmax
from table
where datediff(mm,dmin,dmax)<3
```